# Error while deserializing using DataContactSerializer with C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

```
      private string DeSerialize(string studata)
    {
        dcs= new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string));
        try
        {
            using (var q = new StringReader(studata))
            {
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sr))
                {
                   var k = dcs.ReadObject(reader);
                    return k.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
         {}
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

with the above method got the runtime error "Error in line 1 position 41. Expecting element 'string' from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.. Encountered 'Element' student namespace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you serialize something, you serialize an object into some representation such as XML, JSON, etc.  If the representation is not binary, the result of serialization can be stored in a string.

Your code is trying to take a string and deserialize it into a string.  That does not make sense.

The line

```
dcs= new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string));
```

states that the type of the *serialized object* you are deserializing is type string.  That's probably not what you meant.

Change `typeof(string)` to `typeof(WhateverTypeIPreviouslySerialized)`.

Also, the return type of `DeSerialize` is `string`.  That should also be `WhateverTypeIPreviouslySerialized`.

Unrelated to the core question, I would point out that the empty catch

```
    catch
     {}
```

is bad practice.  It will mask Exceptions that are being thrown and need to be dealt with.  If you wanted to return a specific value when serialization fails, put that value inside the catch statement.